# jquery and ajax page issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am implementing the search functionality through ajax jquery, though I am new in this. I have done that by using keyup event. Whenever type something, according to that letter(s), my searching list has been coming. But thing is that, I am not getting any record when refresh the page. If I search something then only I am getting record and if in that position I delete all the texts typed over the search field, then the correct list of records are coming, but not initially.

```
    $("#search_term").keyup(function(e){ 
                e.preventDefault(); 
                ajax_search(); 
        }); 

    function ajax_search(){ 
      $("#search_results").show(); 
      var search_val=$("#search_term").val(); 
      $.post("user-account-other.php", {search_term : search_val}, function(data){
       if (data.length>0){ 
         $("#search_results").html(data); 
       } 
      }) 
    } 

 <div id="search_results"></div>
```

Now please tell me how can solve this issue.

Comment: Could be me, but I really don't understand the question... You don't get records when you refresh the page? Isn't that normal because you only get the records on keyUp? So, until you start typing nothing shows right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put ajax_search() funcion in on onload of document and also on blur of a text box element then  it will work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure what you're asking. I'd be happy to update this answer with some more information once I can understand the problem. I did, however, want to show you how to better streamline your code.

See: http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$("#search_term").keyup(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    ajax_search(); 
}); 

function ajax_search(){ 
    var url = "user-account-other.php?search_term=" + $("#search_term").val();
    $("#search_results").load(url, function(){
         //Ajax Load is Done
    }).show();
}
```